# Searching through data base for partial and full match integers

Tags: python, database, pandas, parsing, search

I'm trying to search through a dataframe with a column that can have one or more integer values, to match one or more given integers.
The integers in the database has a '-' in between For example

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 1     |1124                |
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 2     |1124-1123           |
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 3     |1124-1234-1642      |
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 3     |1213-1234-1642      |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The objective here is to do a partial and full match, and be able to  and be able to find out how many integers didn't match.

So for example let's say I have find all customers with 1124, the output would look like this(going off the example I provided)

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 1     |1124                |None
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 2     |1124-1123           |1
--------------------------------------------------
| Customer 3     |1124-1234-1642      |2
--------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use `set`**

- define `x` as the test `set`
- make `s` a series of `set`s
- `s - x` creates a series of differences
- `(s - x).str.len()` are the sizes of the differences
- `s & x` is a boolean series indicating whether there is an intersection.  Or in this case, if `x` is in `s`

---

```
x = {'1124'}
s = df['col2'].str.split('-').apply(set)

df.assign(col3=(s - x).str.len())[s & x]

         col1            col2  col3
0  Customer 1            1124     0
1  Customer 2       1124-1123     1
2  Customer 3  1124-1234-1642     2
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['Customer 1', 'Customer 2', 'Customer 3', 'Customer 3'],
    'col2': ['1124', '1124-1123', '1124-1234-1642', '1213-1234-1642']
})
```

Comment: This is amazing, I tried but coudn't come up with how to count number of false :(

Comment: Thank you @Vaishali

Comment: awesome thank you!! Quick question. For col3, how did you create the new column, or does col3=(s - x) do it for you. The original DF only has two columns, I'm not sure how the third column would be added

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.assign` creates a copy of the original dataframe with a new column specified by the keyword=arguments you pass.

Comment: Perfect. Very elegant solution. My code that didn't even work was maybe 6 times the length. Again thanks so much!